# grep on a variable containing a string with a tab

Tags: bash, grep

I have a for loop that loops over a few lines. each line has two strings with a tab separating them e.g

```
chr11   105804693
```

when I pass the variable to grep with a file to search in it returns `"105804693: No such file or directory"`. my code looks like this:

> for line in $(cat list_of_lines);
>       do grep $line file_to_search_in >> output_file;
>       done

I tried to `printf` the variable and it returned `"chr11"` but when I echoed the variable it returned `"chr11 105804693"`

How can I call grep on the variable and have it search for the full line?

Comment: Please add your code to your question.

Comment: If you are calling `grep` from the body of a loop, there may be a better solution that involves only calling `grep` once.

Comment: wrt `I have a for loop that loops over a few lines` - that first sentence identifies the root of your problem. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't added quotes around your variable having the search pattern,

```
search_pattern_variable="chr11 105804693"
grep "$search_pattern_variable" input-file
```

Since your variable had the words `chr11 105804693`, `shell` split up the words into multiple words with the default `IFS` (field-separator) and had used `chr11` as the pattern and `105804693` as the file-name, which it is reporting not seeing such a file.

See what [Word-Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) means in `bash`.

Comment: Variable references should almost always be double-quoted. This is one of the most common beginner mistakes in shell scripting. [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) (recommended, BTW) will automatically flag non-double-quoted variable references as errors.

Comment: Thanks for shellcheck.net. it looks really useful.